# A solution to translating zod error messages using next-intl

Tags: next.js, internationalization, zod, app-router, next-intl

I am looking for a way of translating Zod error messages when using the [next-intl](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl) package. Perhaps an alternative to [Zod-i18n](https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n), instead of [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next).

The reasons for picking next-intl instead of i18next are related to NextJS app router so switching to i18next really isn't an option in this case.

EDIT: I am really looking to translate the default Zod messages, not passing in custom translations per refinement. Bulk translations are what I'm after.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the translation as an argument.

en.json:

```
{
  "home": {
    "errors": {
      "Name is required": "Name is required."
    }
  }
}
```

schemas/index.ts:

```
import * as z from "zod";

export const BaseSchema = (t: (arg: string) => string) =>
  z.object({
    name: z.string().min(1, {message: t("errors.Name is required")})
  });
```

in client code (form):

```
"use client";

import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";
import { BaseSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

export const Form = ()=> {
  const t = useTranslations("home");
  const formSchema = BaseSchema(t);
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: ""
  });
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    // await a server action 
  };
  return(<Form></Form>);
};
```

in server action code:

```
"use server";

import { getTranslations } from "next-intl/server";
import * as z from "zod";
import { BaseSchema } from "@/schemas";

export const create = async (
  values: z.infer<ReturnType<typeof BaseSchema>>
) => {
  const t = await getTranslations("home");
  const paramsSchema = BaseSchema(t);
  const validatedFields = paramsSchema.safeParse(values);
  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    throw new Error("Invalid fields");
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, good shout. I was mainly wondering about bulk editing the pre-existing messages. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Probably the better answer since it doesn't take that much code and is more flexible in terms of messages then zod-i18n.
I would add better typing here with `export const BaseSchema = (t: ReturnType<typeof useTranslations<'home'>>) => `

And I'd export schema types from the same file with
`export type BaseSchemaType = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof BaseSchema>>;`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and was looking into alternatives of [zod-i18n](https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n) that work with next-intl. After looking into the code of zod-i18n I realized that it's not that big of a deal to adapt for next-intl. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/gcascio/next-intl-zod) and a blog post [here](https://www.gcasc.io/blog/next-intl-zod).
Not as convenient as having a package out of the box but it solved my problem for now.